# Реализация бокового меню в DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Использую в приложении *DrawerLayout*. Сделал боковую менюшку с помощью кастомного `DrawerAdapter`. С таким подходом для итемов в менюшке надо создать:

- отдельный файл xml c разметкой, в котором будут не все итемы! а
  только 1
- запихнуть в этот файл разметку всех возможных *view*, которые могут
  быть у элементов
- создать класс модели для итемов

Дальше в `class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItemModel>` мы перебираем все созданные нами итемы и просто скрываем ненужные вьюхи у конкретного итема.

И когда я все это делал - было ощущения костыля.
Чуть позже я увидел как это просто делается с NavigationView. Не приходится писать уродливый адаптер и разметка делается в одном файле сразу для всех вьюх.

Так вот вопрос. Оба способа имеют право на жинизь или адаптер это из прошлого?

Comment: мне кажется, что боковое меню в прошлом)) Сейчас все фанатеют от нижнего меню, а дизайн верстают так, чтобы все была растолкано внутри (например, вк - хотя у них это получилось плохо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По опыту реальных проектов обычно применяется `NavigationView`. Он по гайдланам гугл, у него много удобных фитч, пишется проще.

`DrawerAdapter` это из тех времен, когда гугл еще не создало универсальные дизайнерские элементы и каждый делал `NavigationView` как мог и считал удобным. Хотя в каких-то экзотичных случаях `DrawerAdapter` может быть валиден

P.S Пока не пометили какой-либо способ depricated, скорее всего он так или иначе имеет смысл